# Installing Entity Framework fails in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm reading/coding along with the Apress book **Pro ASP.NET MVC 5** by Adam Freeman. In chapter 7 (p. 174), we're supposed to install Entity Framework using the following commands:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -projectname SportsStore.Domain
Install-Package EntityFramework -projectname SportsStore.WebUI
```

But this fails. Here is the output:

> Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to project 'SportsStore.Domain', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'
>   Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>   Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
>   Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
>   Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages'
>   Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages'
>   Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to 'packages.config'
>   Executing script file 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1'
>   Executing script file 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'
>
> Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
>   Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to SportsStore.Domain
>   Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Removed package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' from 'packages.config'
>   Removing package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' from folder 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages'
>   Access to the path 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' is denied.
>   Access to the path 'EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' is denied.
>   Removed package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' from folder 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages'
>   Install-Package : An item with the same key has already been added.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package EntityFramework -projectname SportsStore.Domain
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> One or more packages could not be completely uninstalled: 'C:\git\SportsStore\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3'. Restart Visual Studio to finish uninstall.

The book is instructing us to install specific versions of all other libraries (e.g. `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc 5.0.0`), but does not mention which version of EF to install, so I've tried installing different versions of EF, but keep getting the same error. (`Install failed. Rolling back...`)

I'm running VS2015 as administrator.

Comment: Just tried installing EF to a clean new MVC-project, and that works just fine, so this might be related to versioning?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the question. I also has the same issue while reading the same book.

Answer (score 10):

Seems NuGet itself was causing these issues (probably related to https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1239, as I was seeing the same 'always rolling back' issue as discussed in that thread)

Updating NuGet solved it for me. (Updated from version `3.0.60624.657` to `3.1.60724.766`)

[image: Updating NuGet]

Comment: I was on Visual Studio 2015 update 2. I upgraded it to update 3 and it worked. For sure nuget package manager would have also got updated during this update.

Answer (score 1):

These references were set up earlier in the project:

```
SportsStore.WebUI -> SportsStore.Domain 
SportsStore.UnitTests -> SportsStore.Domain and SportsStore.WebUI
```

I removed the references for each project and then ran the install-package command for the Entity Framework as directed.  That worked fine.

I then re-added the references.

Comment: This is a useful comment but does not really serve as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the EF nuget packages installed on your solution and then reinstall the only one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect references between projects and than try to install EF. Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Relaunching Visual Studio as Admin and retry to install the package did the trick for me.