# Can't Install Entity Framework via NuGet in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, nuget-package

I want to make use of Entity Framework in my project.

So I opened up my package installer console in Visual Studio 2015 and I typed in the following:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -projectname SportsStore.Domain
```

But I get an error! Here is what I get:
[image: Error]

Comment: What version of Nuget? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297647/installing-entity-framework-fails-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Package Manager Console Host Version 3.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Updating NuGet solved it for me.